# How to fix an error message "Error in round(pwfst, 3) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function"

Tags: r

I am using

```
pwfst <-stamppFst(gl, nboots=1, percent=95, nclusters=1)
round(pwfst,3)
```

This works perfectly if `nboots = 1,` but when I try `nboots = 3,` 
I get the following error:

```
Error in round(pwfst, 3) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

I want to eventually use `nboots = 100`

I have read several posts with

```
non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

But none relate to this problem. One post advised advised ensuring I only had the necessary packages loaded. I have done that and no change.

Has anyone any ideas please?
thanks.

EDIT: `pwfst`is not a list.
It has this form - there are 5 more columns

```
              Bees Nest Ridge_12 Bees Nest Ridge_15 Broken Back Trail Cousins Creek
Bees Nest Ridge_12                 NA                 NA                NA            NA
Bees Nest Ridge_15              0.092                 NA                NA            NA
Broken Back Trail               0.124              0.067                NA            NA
Cousins Creek                   0.396              0.352             0.376            NA
Sawpit Rd                       0.104              0.046             0.077         0.349
Wallaby Rocks                   0.450              0.384             0.421         0.540
Bees Nest Ridge_13              0.161              0.098             0.132         0.403
Wingen Maid                     0.433              0.376             0.409         0.537
Bees Nest Ridge_14              0.086              0.025             0.056         0.354
```

Second edit:

```
str(pwfst)
```

returns

```
num [1:9, 1:9] NA 0.0922 0.1243 0.3964 0.1038 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "Bees Nest Ridge_12" "Bees Nest Ridge_15" "Broken Back Trail" "Cousins Creek" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:9] "Bees Nest Ridge_12" "Bees Nest Ridge_15" "Broken Back Trail" "Cousins Creek" ...
```

> 

Hopefully that is enough info for someone to be able to help me.
Thanks,
Ruth P

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the `stamppFst()` function reads: "If nboots<2, no bootstrapping is performed and therefore only a matrix of Fst values is returned." Therefore, when `pwfst` is a result of an analysis using 1 boot you supply a matrix to the `round` function, which the `round` function can handle. In other cases (when nboots >= 2), you supply a list to the `round` function, which it is not able to handle this way.

If `pwfst` is a list, you could run `lapply(pwfst, round)` so that it runs round on every matrix in the list.

Comment: Thanks @Lenny. But `pwfst` is not a list. I would call it a matrix.                   Bees Nest Ridge_12 Bees Nest Ridge_15 Broken Back Trail Cousins Creek
Bees Nest Ridge_12                 NA                 NA                NA            NA
Bees Nest Ridge_15              0.092                 NA                NA            NA
Broken Back Trail               0.124              0.067                NA            NA
Cousins Creek                   0.396              0.352             0.376            NA
Sawpit Rd                       0.104              0.046

Comment: Please read the documentation again.  The function returns a list consisting of 2 matrices and 1 dataframe in case nboots >= 2.

Comment: Thanks @Lennyy. I did try `lapply(pwfst, round)` and got this error:

`Error in Math.data.frame(list(Population1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: Population1, Population2`, which I cannot deal with. 
But, I have realised that by leaving out the rounding command, I get an output, so all is good thanks.